# Is there a reason why I can't extract the price data from the Nike Website using selenium and Python

Tags: python, css, selenium-webdriver, xpath, web-crawler

I am currently building a Python script that takes the price of trainers from the Nike website and pushes the price into a CSV file. Originally, the code took the element where the price data lives but after it failed, I switched to using  CSS selectors, since Nike's prices for its products are wrapped in CSS. But when I ran the script, it couldn't extract the price data. I was stumped, so I modified the script to account for elements that are dynamically loaded in Javascript after the initial page load. But after all of that, I still can't get it to push the price and the product into the CSV file. I deciced to modifiy the code to extract the code using xPath. However all of that I still couldn't extract the price data and push it through the CSV file.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
# Get the website using the Chrome web driver
browser = webdriver.Chrome()

# Create an empty DataFrame to store the results
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Product", "Price"])

# Define a list of websites to scrape
websites = [
    'https://www.nike.com/gb/t/dunk-low-retro-shoe-Kd1wZr/DD1391-103',
    'https://www.nike.com/gb/t/dunk-low-retro-shoe-QgD9Gv/DD1391-100',
    'https://www.nike.com/gb/t/dunk-low-retro-shoes-p6gmkm/DV0833-400'
]

# Loop through the websites
for website in websites:
    browser.get(website)
    try:
        # Attempt to find the price element by its xPath
        price = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="PDP"]/div[2]/div/div[4]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div')))
        # If found, extract the text and add to the DataFrame
        df = df.append({"Product": website, "Price": price.text}, ignore_index=True)
        print("Price for", website, ":", price.text)
    except:
        # If the element is not found, print an error message
        print("Price not found for", website)

# Close the browser
browser.quit()

# Save data frame data into an Excel CSV file
df.to_csv(r'PriceList.csv', index=False)
```

The code is suppose to take the element where the price data lives and push into a CSV file
[A visual aid of what the code shoudl do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3rNU.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
df = df.append({"Product": website, "Price": price.text}, ignore_index=True)
```

`append` was removed from pandas.
Instead you can use `_append`.

```py
df = df._append({"Product": website, "Price": price.text}, ignore_index=True)
```

For some reason, `text` doesn't seem to work (on my computer).
Instead, you can use the `get_attribute("innerHTML")`

Here is the final code.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from chromedriver_py import binary_path
import time
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

svc = Service(executable_path=binary_path)

# Get the website using the Chrome web driver
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=svc)

# Create an empty DataFrame to store the results
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Product", "Price"])

# Define a list of websites to scrape
websites = [
    'https://www.nike.com/gb/t/dunk-low-retro-shoe-Kd1wZr/DD1391-103',
    'https://www.nike.com/gb/t/dunk-low-retro-shoe-QgD9Gv/DD1391-100',
    'https://www.nike.com/gb/t/dunk-low-retro-shoes-p6gmkm/DV0833-400'
]

# Loop through the websites
for website in websites:
    browser.get(website)
    try:
        # Attempt to find the price element by its xPath
        price = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="PDP"]/div[2]/div/div[4]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div')))

        # If found, extract the text and add to the DataFrame
        df = df._append({"Product": website, "Price": price.get_attribute('innerHTML')}, ignore_index=True)
        print("Price for", website, ":", price.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
    except:
        # If the element is not found, print an error message
        print("Price not found for", website)

# Close the browser
browser.quit()

# Save data frame data into an Excel CSV file
df.to_csv(r'PriceList.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: "append was removed from pandas. Instead you can use _append." Does this mean that append was originally a part of the pandas package before it got removed in an update?

Comment: Yeah. It got removed on pandas 2.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is only ment to get a better XPath. I don't know if that is the cause of your problem.

I would use a `@id`-attribute that is closer to your target. Which is this one:

`@id='pdp_product_title'`

But it seems like there are somehow **two** html-blocks with the same h1/@id, which is not valid...but to overcome this you could use this explicit XPath:

```
(//div[h1[@id='pdp_product_title']])[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]
```

An simpler XPath version would be this one:

```
(//div[h1[@id='pdp_product_title']])[2]//div[data-test='product-price'][1]
```

The `[1]` predicats are just to tell the XPath engine not to look any further than the first one. Could be a little performance-advantage.